# Value having double equal signs in Get Request?

Tags: http, httprequest, blockchain

I know a similar question has been asked before but I wanted to know if this is a valid GET request?

```
https://somenet-tx-rest.mydomainx.io/cosmos/tx/v1beta1/txs?events=message.sender=Tx19mlsjsh948d6xzyllgt990hshv455ravfdj2r7
```

I tried sending this and I got the following response:

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "\nparse error near equal (line 1 symbol 16 - line 1 symbol 17):\n\"=\"\n: invalid request",
    "details": []
}
```

To provide more information, if I submit the same GET request without the `=Tx19mlsjsh948d6xzyllgt990hshv455ravfdj2r7` :

```
https://somenet-tx-rest.mydomainx.io/cosmos/tx/v1beta1/txs?events=message.sender
```

The response is:

```
{
    "code": 3,
    "message": "rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = invalid event; event message.sender should be of the format: {eventType}.{eventAttribute}={value}: invalid request",
    "details": []
}
```

I'm not sure how to provide the value for `message.sender` as `message.sender` seems to be needed for the `event` key?

I'm trying to use the following endpoint:
https://functionx.github.io/fx-core/swagger-ui/#/Service/GetTxsEvent with an address argument for the `events` parameter

Comment: `if this is a valid GET request?` Yes it is, but may not be in the structure your technology wants to. You should edit your question and add the tecnologies you're using so people can help you better. This may also change your question, you may want to focus on solving the problem FOR the tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update my Perl code for new RPC endpoint. My old code looked as follows:

```
  "$lcd_address/txs?message.sender=$delegator&message.module=staking&delegate.validator=$validator"
```

and I changed it to:

```
  "$lcd_address/cosmos/tx/v1beta1/txs?events=message.sender='$delegator'&events=message.module='staking'&events=delegate.validator='$validator'"
```

Please be aware that JSON payload changed between the endpoints.